# Run insert statement x number of times

Tags: t-sql

I have two tables. One table `A` has n rows of data and the other table `B` is empty. I want to `insert` n rows into table `B`, 1 row for each row in table `A`. Table `B` will have a couple of fields from table `A` in it, including a foreign key from table `A`.

In the end I want one row in `B` for each row in `A`. To do this I used:

```
INSERT INTO B(Col1
             ,Col2
             ,Col3
             ,Col4
             ,Col5
             );
SELECT 100
      ,25 
      ,'ABC'
      ,1
      ,A.ID
FROM Auctions A
```

Now, I've put this code in a stored procedure and this SP takes an `int` param called `NumInserts`.

I want to insert `n * NumInserts` rows. So, if n is 10 and NumInserts is 5 I want to run this code 5 * 10 (50) times.

In other words for each row in `table A` I want to `insert` 5 rows in `table B`. How would I do that?

Comment: I would set up a number table that has numbers from 1 to a large upper bound (1,000,000 or something). Then you could CROSS APPLY Auctions to the numbers table where Number <= NumInserts. The results if n was 10 would be each row duplicated 5 times before being inserted into B.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
create procedure insert_into_b
    @numInserts int
as
begin
    while @numInserts > 0
    begin
        insert into b (id)
        select id from a
        set @numInserts = @numInserts - 1
    end
end

exec insert_into_b 2
```

Answer (score 11):

This is a hack and I wouldn't recommend using it in production or big volumes of data.  However, in development quick-and-dirty scenarios I found it often useful:

Use [`GO \[count\]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) to execute a batch of commands a specified number of times.

Concretely, if you had a stored procedure called `InsertAIntoB`, you could run this in Management Studio:

```
exec InsertAIntoB
GO 10
```

*(replace `10` with whatever NumInserts is)*

Comment: A nick hack - in fact I am using it for a quick and dirty scenario.  For some reason GO @NumInserts didn't work - I wonder how the escaping helps.

Comment: @SachinKainth Actually I don't think it works with variables. That's because `GO <n>` is not really T-SQL, but some sort of macro that SQL Server Management Studio understands.

Answer (score 10):

I prefer to avoid looping when I can, just so I don't have to maintain some easily breakable and somewhat ugly loop structure in my stored procedure.

You could easily do this with a `Numbers` table, the `CROSS APPLY` statement, and your existing `INSERT` statement.

Given that your numbers table would look like this:

```
Number
======
0
1
2
...
```

Your SQL statement simply becomes:

```
INSERT INTO B 
(
    [Col1]
    ,[Col2]
    ,[Col3]
    ,[Col4]
    ,[Col5]
)
SELECT 
    100 
    ,25
    ,'ABC'
    ,1
    ,a.ID
FROM 
    Auctions a
CROSS APPLY
    Numbers n
WHERE
    n.Number BETWEEN 1 AND @NumInserts
```

Numbers tables can be useful if use appropriately. If you're unfamiliar with them, here are a few resources and some pros/cons:

- http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/ (the code to create a numbers table in this article is shown below)
- http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=NumbersTable
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable

Maybe this solution is overkill if `@NumInserts` is always going to be a reasonably small number, but if you already have a Numbers table sitting around, you might as well take advantage of it!

**UPDATE**:

Here's a quick and dirty method to populate a numbers table from 0 to 65,535:

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers
(
    Number INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)
        WITH FILLFACTOR = 100
)
GO

INSERT INTO Numbers
SELECT
    (a.Number * 256) + b.Number AS Number
FROM 
(
    SELECT number
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE 
        type = 'P'
        AND number <= 255
) a (Number),
(
    SELECT number
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE 
        type = 'P'
        AND number <= 255
) b (Number)
GO
```

<sub>**Credit:** http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/</sub>

Comment: This is good.  I think I might use this next time I have this problem.  I bet there is a quick and easy way to populate the numbers table too.

Comment: @SachinKainth: I updated my answer with a quick and dirty method to get a small numbers table.

Comment: I down voted. I disagree with tables to hold things like dates, numbers etc.  Once I even saw one that had only two rows,  (True, and False).   Rather than use a table to store numbers, if you want to avoid the loop, use a CTE. (and why try to avoid loop? - no matter WHAT you do the computer MUST be looping somewhere. the only difference is at what level of abstraction the loop is mechanized!!)

Comment: @CharlesBretana: I agree that somewhere there is a loop; my argument is: why should I bother maintaining the ugly looping code when I could just add a few extra instructions in my already-existing query?

Comment: @Cory, to each his own I suppose. From my perspective, your code to create the numbers table is (Shall I say) unattractive... Compare it with the CTE that creates the same numbers>>>
      `With nums(num) As
       (Select @N Union All
        Select num - 1
        From nums
        Where num > 1)`

Comment: @CharlesBretana: That's not my code, and it's really a run-once-and-forget solution. The recursive CTE approach is an option, but I feel that it just introduces another layer of complexity. I only recently added Numbers tables to toolset to solve the exact problem of removing recursive CTEs that were drastically downgrading performance of a query I was working on.

Comment: @Cory  What performance problems with CTE??  The highest level of recursion possible is 32367, and the CTE that generates that many integers takes less than 50 ms.   What are you using CTEs for ?  If you are experiencing performance problems using a CTE, than I suspect you are misusing them, (i.e., using them for some complex recursive table-access process where the issue is really the process you are executing in each recursion, not the recursion itself.)  Like any other tool, CTEs have their place, and their pitfalls.  Painting any technology with a broad brush, (good or bad) is unwise.

Comment: @CharlesBretana: Well said. I agree everything has its place. The problem I was solving was introduced by somebody else; who, like you said, was misusing them. Seems like we each have our preferences; I just prefer going the static Number table route to avoid writing procedural code when I don't really need to. I also chose this route so that if another similar problem presents itself down the road, I'm not copying/pasting that recursive CTE code in multiple places, Given that all it's doing is generating a number list, I might as well just use a static one. Right? Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
 Create procedure DoitNTimes 
 @N integer = 1
 As
 Set NoCount On

    While @N > 0 Begin
       Insert B (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
       Select 100, 25, 'ABC', 1, A.ID
       From Auctions A
       -- -----------------------------------
       Set @N -= 1
    End
```

If using SQL Server 2005 or earlier replace the `Set @N -= 1'  with`Set @N = @N-1`

and if you really want to avoid loop using T-SQL variables, then use  a CTE, not a disk-based table:

```
 Create procedure DoitNTimes 
 @N integer = 1
 As
 Set NoCount On

     With nums(num) As
       (Select @N Union All
        Select num - 1
        From nums
        Where num > 1)
     Insert B (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
     Select 100, 25, 'ABC', 1, A.ID
     From Auctions A Full Join nums
     Option(MaxRecursion 10000)
```

but of course, this is also still looping, just like any solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Very late answer but there is no need to loop and it's a little simpler than Corey's good answer;

```
DECLARE @n int = 10;
INSERT INTO B(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5);
SELECT 100,25,'ABC',1,A.ID
FROM Auctions A
JOIN (SELECT TOP(@n) 1 [junk] FROM sys.all_objects) as copies ON 1 = 1
```

You could use any table in the join as long as it has the number of rows you'll need. You could also change "1 [junk]" to "ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id) [copyno]" if you wanted a copy number somewhere in the insert table.

Hopefully this will save someone a little work down the road...

Answer (score 0):

Try this (on SQL server databases):

```
DECLARE @NumInserts SMALLINT = 3

INSERT INTO B (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
    SELECT 100, 25, 'ABC', 1, A.ID
    FROM Auctions A
        JOIN master.dbo.spt_values numbers ON numbers.number < @NumInserts
    WHERE numbers.[type] = 'P'
```

- **Note**: This will only work if `@NumInserts` is less than or equal to 2048
- `master.dbo.spt_values WHERE type = 'P'` is just a built-in SQL Server table of numbers from 0 to 2047