# Is there a way to set how many times a value could be inserted in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Ex.

```
SELECT A_NUM, [No. of Entries], Address  
FROM Table_1
```

Output:

```
123222, 5, 'MNL'
122334, 6, 'GS'
```

Then insert this data into another table.

```
INSERT INTO Table_entries 
VALUES ('123222', 'MNL')
```

should run 5 times based on the no of entries. (6 times for '122334', 'GS')

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run insert statement x number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476598/run-insert-statement-x-number-of-times)

Comment: @CodeCaster can you post the query for my concern? i read the link you provided i think we have a different scenario, thanks

Comment: Are you trying to *populate* a table (or result set) with a particular number of rows (what I get from the question body) or *constrain* the number of rows that the second table can contain (what I get from the question title)?

Comment: Sounds like you want to SELECT, JOIN, and INSERT. If so, that can be done.

Comment: @Byron perhaps try reading the answers, and not dismissing the link based on the question. The `CROSS APPLY` solution is also mentioned in the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a `CROSS JOIN` of some large tables like this

```
insert into table_entries
select t1.a_num, t1.address 
from table1 t1
cross apply (
    select top (t1.no) 1 
    from sys.sysobjects 
    cross join sys.all_columns
) t(n)
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2c68c430658dd116de4ac46278c72683)

`CROSS JOIN` can be possibly replaced by some [sequence generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425546/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-between-two-numbers).